# How does the Ubuntu kernel version relate to the upstream version?

Tags: kernel, versions, upstream

On Oneiric, `uname -r` prints "3.0.0-14-generic".

Does this mean that I am running an Ubuntu kernel based on the upstream (Linux) 3.0.0? Or is it actually based on Linux version 3.0.14?

I have tried cloning the Linux kernel repo and adding the Ubuntu repo as a remove, but commands like `git show-branch Ubuntu-3.0.0-14.23 v3.0.14` show these two tags diverging at Linux 3.0.4, and I can't see any commits near the tip of the Ubuntu tag that indicate a rebase to a new upstream version.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is based on upstream `3.0.0`

The number 14 is not part of the kernel version number and is an Ubuntu release number only. If you look at the package's control file you should be able to see the changes between each release.

Comment: Looking at the `Ubuntu-3.0.0-14.23` tag of http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-oneiric.git/, one of the recent commit messages is "Linux 3.0.9". Does that mean it includes some or all of 3.0.9, despite being theoretically based on 3.0.0?

Comment: Looks like you're right, I have no idea why they would do something like that! It's confusing and not particularly helpful. It ma have something to do with the 2.6 to 3.x numbering change: maybe their scripts aren't able to change the third digit?