# Why does 3rd digit in Ubuntu kernel version not match 3rd digit in its mainline upstream kernel version number?

Tags: kernel, packaging, versions

From the Ubuntu Kernel FAQ  ( https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ ) :

> Given an Ubuntu kernel package version how do we find the release it
>   is from? The kernel package version is of the following form
>   2.6.35-6.9. The numbers before the - represent the base upstream version from which this kernel was forked, the first number following
>   the - represents the ABI number, the final number is an upload number.

This seems to contradict another item in the same FAQ:

> Given an Ubuntu kernel package version how do we find the exact
>   mainline release it is based on? The exact upstream mainline tag from
>   which the Ubuntu kernels were forked can be found in the [mainline
>   kernel mapping](http://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html) table.

If we look at an excerpt from the mainline kernel mapping table we can see for example:

Ubuntu Kernel Version | Ubuntu Kernel Tag | Mainline Kernel Version

3.19.0-7.7 | Ubuntu-3.19.0-7.7 | 3.19.0

3.19.0-8.8 | Ubuntu-3.19.0-8.8 | 3.19.1

3.19.0-9.9 | Ubuntu-3.19.0-9.9 | 3.19.1

3.19.0-10.10 | Ubuntu-3.19.0-10.10 | 3.19.2

3.19.0-11.11 | Ubuntu-3.19.0-11.11 | 3.19.3

Here we see in the third column, as the mainline kernel version's third digit steps (3.19.0 -> 3.19.3) the Ubuntu kernel version's third digit does not step, it stays at 3.19.0. The third digit is the last digit before the "-" in the label. Does this not contradict the first FAQ answer above which says "The numbers before the - represent the base upstream version from which this kernel was forked..." ?

Comment: I just noticed this version mismatch while running 'make kernelversion' in the kernel headers directory for my installed kernel. Also curious about the mismatch. Note that `cat /proc/version_signature` of the running kernel prints both the version string that matches the released package, and the version string that matches the header source.

Comment: Related to question http://askubuntu.com/questions/91922/how-does-the-ubuntu-kernel-version-relate-to-the-upstream-version